# Going from Berlin to Munich by car

Tags: road-trips, berlin, munich, leipzig, nuremberg

I have one day to go from Berlin to Nuremberg (hotel checkin until 22hs). 
And next day going to Munich (hotel checking until 21hs)

Which stops do you recommend?

Would be it ok to go from Berlin to Dresden, then Liepzig, then Nuremberg? Are those cities worth visiting the same day even when I have to travel more?

Also there are other suggested stops in a guided tours like Potsdam, Worlitz, Erfurt, Moritzburg, Weimar.. but as I have time from the morning to 22hs I have to be sure which stops are really worth it.

Then I have no idea of any interesting stop from Nuremberg to Munich. May be Munich worth so much so I should go directly there? (I will be there two nights)

PD: Please explain why do you recommend each city. That way even this being subjective, any of us can take it and think if it's valid

Comment: That's a lot of different cities to see in one day!

Comment: Whether something would make a good stop for you is completely personal to you. We don't know you, we don't know what you like. Even if we knew, any answer would be of very little use to anyone except you. For these reasons, we don't answer this kind of question on this site.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I've put a PD there which I think will help make this useful for everybody

Comment: @Nicolas we don't do itinerary plannings and recommendations, see [our FAQ](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and your question should remain closed as both too broad and off-topic, I'm afraid.

Comment: @mts I understand everybody is different, but I think the fact of asking -why- is a valid fix for the subjective issue. Can this issue be reviewed?

Comment: @Nicolas opinions with reasons remain opinions. These are the basic Travel SE rules, somewhat of a constitution for this site. If you feel this should be changed, take it to our Meta, but it would be beneficial if you were a bit more of an established user here. Otherwise you can ask for recommendations in our chat.

Comment: @Nicolas No, it's still completely subjective. It's also overly broad, since it's asking about a largely random selection of German towns, whose only relationship to one another is that they're on the road from one random German town to another. Essentially, the question has now become "Please write a tourist guide for each of the following towns." We don't do that.

Answer (score 3):

Google says that the road trip from Berlin to Nuremberg takes a bit over four hours. This does not count the time to get from your hotel in Berlin to the highway entry, and from the highway exit in Nuremberg to your hotel. It would be more realistic to make it 5-6 hours.

I think you should make *at most* one stop between Berlin and Nuremberg, and you should consider to skip Nuremberg completely to spend more time in Berlin and Munich.

Ask yourself what you want to see. Scenic sights? Old buildings? Famous artwork? Genuine Bavarian food in a *Gasthaus*? The Reichstag?

Comment: -1 for telling them to skip Nuremberg - just kidding. But it is a nice place and since the OP has booked a hotel there...

Comment: @mts  yeah it's too much driving for one day so Nuremberg is a forced stop

Comment: @o-m scenic sights, old buildings, food, beer :) .. I don't know what is the reichstag.. so choosing between leipzig and dresden, what city would be worth visiting (and why)?

Comment: @Nicolas, TSE is not the site to ask this kind of question. There are too many options and the choice of one over an other is personal opinion and neither are allowed here. These questions get closed. If you have a specific question about one city you might be able to ask it, but from here to here Q will never fit the format.